# how to write a regex command that match several dividers including any number of spaces, but not space(s) between equal sign?

Tags: javascript, regex

I read many posts and found out that seems `look-behind` is not supported by JS regex. Is there a way I can still do the part to exclude matching that is any equal symbols with any number of spaces in front or after it?

So far what I got is `\s+|,|\(|\)|(?! \s*?=)`
this regex will match all dividers like any number of spaces, ",", "(", or ")", but not working properly for the last part where I want to exclude any spaces that is found before or after a `=` symbol.

so the moment I did `(?! \s*?=)` is when all hell breaks out. However, I can see that if I just use `\s*?=` with a pipe, it actually matches `any equal symbols with any number of spaces in front or after it`.

sandbox: https://regexr.com/4fgop

Is there way I can still do this in javascript?

Example (by using the regex with `STRING.split(regexrulehere)`)

**Input String:**
`my-app command, arg1 arg2 arg3   =val1, arg4 = val2)`

**Expected Output:**

```
[
'my-app',
'command',
'arg1',
'arg2',
'arg3=val1', // or `arg3   =val1` is fine as well
'arg4=val2', // or `arg4 = val2` is fine as well
]
```

Comment: You have spaces around `=` in the input string, and you cannot expect to get `arg4=val2` (without spaces) after a single `split`. Do it in two "regex" steps: `s.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, '=').split(/[\s,()]+/).filter(Boolean)`, or `s.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, '=').match(/[^\s,()]+/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces around `=` in the input string, and you cannot expect to get `arg4=val2` (without spaces) after a single `split`.

Do it in two "regex" steps:

```
s = s.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, '=').match(/[^\s,()]+/g)
```

The `\s*=\s*` matches any 0+ whitespaces, `=` and 0+ whitespaces, and this `replace` removes all whitespaces around `=`. `.match(/[^\s,()]+/g)` will extract all chunks of 1+ chars other than whitespace, `,`, `(` and `)` chars as `[^...]` is a [*negated character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

JS demo:

```js
var s = "my-app command, arg1 arg2 arg3=val1, arg4=val2)";
console.log(s.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, '=').match(/[^\s,()]+/g));
```

If you want to split, use

```
s.replace(/\s*=\s*/g, '=').split(/[\s,()]+/).filter(Boolean)
```

Note that `filter(Boolean)` is required to remove empty elements if any.

Answer (score 0):

As you state that including the whitespace chars is also fine, another option could be to not match parenthesis, comma, equals sign or a whitespace char using a negated character class `[^\s(),=]+`.

Then follow the match by an optional part `(?:....)?` that matches an equals sign surrounded by whitespace chars and again use the negated character class:

```
[^\s(),=]+(?:\s*=\s*[^\s(),=]+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8v9XWU/1)